# Submit form using dynamicallly added fields with the same name in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2010

I have a ASP.net Web page using VB as the language, I have created a form where it asks for 3 different input fields as follows, but the user has the option to add these three fields again for multiple form inputs to make their lives easier and this task faster.

```
<label>Test Number:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="test_number.1" name="test_number.1" value=""/>
</label>
<label>
    Score:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="score.1" id="score.1" placeholder="Required" value="" />
</label>
<label>Comments:<input type="text" name="comments.1" id="comments.1" value="," placeholder="Comments Necessary for future reference" size="70" />
```

Looking at the submission of the data via firebug this is what it's posting to the serve if you submit only one set of fields.

```
test_number.1=12555&score.1=75&comments=testing
```

Looking at the submission of the data via firebug this is what it's posting to the serve if you submit multiple set of fields.

```
test_number.1=12555&score.1=75&comments=testing&test_number.1=12555&score.1=75&comments=testing&test_number.1=12555&score.1=75&comments=testing
```

Now I need to insert these values into a database, I know how to do this via PHP utilizing [] and then dealing with it on the backend. But I'm still learning asp.net and seem to be having some major issues on how to get this to work. If anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: Are the same names/ids being used multiple times? You should probably change the ids when adding the new fields - unsure if that's a typo.

Comment: Im using jquery to add the fields dynamically and the test_number.1 is then updated to test_number.2 and the same applies to the other two fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution can be:

1st set of controls:

```
<input type="text" name="testnumber" />
<input type="text" name="testscore" />
<input type="text" name="testcomments" />
```

add next set

```
 <input type="text" name="testnumber" />
<input type="text" name="testscore" />
<input type="text" name="testcomments" />
```

and so one.

On server side:

```
var testnumbers = Request["testnumbers"];// comma seperated values
var testscores = Request["testnumbers"];// comma seperated values
var testcomments = Request["testcomments"]; // comma seperted values.
```

split all values by comma. you will get array of values for each

```
 string[] testnoList = testnumbers.split(',');
    string[] testscoresList = testscores .split(',');
    string[] testcommentsList = testcomments .split(',');

   for(int i=0; i<testnoList.Lenght; i++)
   {
       var testno = testnoList[i];
       var score = testscoresList[i];
       var comments = testcommentsList[i];
       // do whatever you want here
   }
```

Comment: ok I understand that part, but how would you get the values to stay grouped together so that they are inserted in order, example all 1st set of controls grouped for database insertion, then all next set, and so on?